# How to strip text from string if contained

Tags: php, strip

I have a string `$current_url` that can contain 2 different values:

```
http://url.com/index.php&lang=en
or
http://url.com/index.php&lang=jp
```

in both cases I need to strip the query part so I get: http://url.com/index.php

How can I do this in php?

Thank you.

Comment: I think that https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php is the function you need

Comment: I only want to remove the query lang. Will this remove also other queries?

Comment: It will actually parse the url breaking it down into smaller "parts". you can do whatever you want with those parts later.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [strtok](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) to remove the query string from url.

```
<?php
echo $url=strtok('http://url.com/index.php&lang=jp','&');
?>
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/eoWkY)

Answer based on comment.

You can use preg_replace
https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/remove-specific-parameter-from-url-query-string-php/

```
<?php
$url = 'http://url.com/index.php?page=site&lang=jp';

function remove_query_string($url_name, $key) {
    $url = preg_replace('/(?:&|(\?))' . $key . '=[^&]*(?(1)&|)?/i', "$1", $url_name);
    $url = rtrim($url, '?');
    $url = rtrim($url, '&');
    return $url;
}

echo remove_query_string($url, 'lang');

?>
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/uaju8)

Comment: That looks good. But I only want to remove the query lang. Will this remove also other queries?

Comment: If you want to remove only query string which contain lang add the condition like - if (strpos($url, '&lang')){
 echo $url=strtok($url,'&');
}

Comment: I tried but that still removes all the other queries. Lets say $url is `http://url.com/index.php?page=site&lang=jp` I only want to remove `lang` and not `page`

Comment: Based on comments I added one more solution with DEMO. Please heck :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Solution

`$url = 'http://url.com/index.php&lang=en';
$array = explode('&', $url);
echo $new_url  =$array[0];`

Answer (score 0):

To only remove the lang query do this

```html
$url = 'http://url.com/index.php&lang=en&id=1';
$array = explode('&lang=en', $url);
echo $new_url  = $array[0] .''.$array[1];

//output http://url.com/index.php&id=1

So this way it only removes the lang query and keep other queries
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of your `lang` parameter is always of length 2, which should be the case for languages, you could use:

```
if(strpos($current_url, '&lang=') !== false){
    $current_url = str_replace(substr($current_url, strpos($current_url, '&lang='), 8), '', $current_url);
}
```

If the substring `"&lang="` is present in `$current_url`, it removes a substring of length 8, starting at the `"&lang="` position. So it basically removes `"&lang="` plus the 2 following chars.